How to add a new user dialog
In Qt Creator, after creating a Qt Widgets App, taking the defaults, there is a file named mainwindow.ui.  When opened, the user can drag and drop standard tools on it, such as push buttons.
What are the steps needed to get Qt Creator to create a new dialog, represented by, let's call it quadratic.ui.  The user will be able to use it in the same manner as mainwindow.ui.
I suspect earlier versions of Qt Creator will use very close to the same process.
I have tried writing code to just open a new dialog, but was not able to get that to work. And if it did work, I suspect it would not provide the ability to drag and drop tools on the new dialog.
I use: Windows 11, Qt Creator 12.0.2, C++.

Does this answer your question? How to create second QT .ui form?
